# Is exist standard iOS pop up for enable access location?

Tags: ios, swift, location

I have Swift app and get location access via LocationManager in my app.
If user set '**NO**' access to app for location, and now want to set '**YES**'.
I set a button for ask again. so when tap on button i show pop up and ask '*Do you want to enable location access?*'. if clicked on yes it goes to iPhone setting.
But i want to know is there standard pop up in **apple iOS Swift** for this case? (Like set something in plist and ...)
Thank you.

Comment: No there is not.

Answer (score 0):

No. You need to create your own methode of redirecting the user to the settings to change the location settings for your app.

Most apps show the status if it is allowed to use the location. And an explanation how the user can allow it again.